# MySQL with mutiple threads and processes

Tags: c, database, mysql

I'm developing a telecom messaging platform in C, and I'm going to need multiple processes to be working with MySQL DB.

How can I make two processes read/write to/from a Mysql DB and, if/when one of them goes down, get the other to seamlessly take over the work until the dead process gets back to work? I was thinking/googling some options and am stuck in place where I don't know which one to choose.

What I think so far is that table lock is not the best option to go for, as it will stall the other process until the table is unlocked. The other option is to use row-level locks or manual locks, but I can't find the best way to do it.

Comment: just a comment, check out Erlang/OTP as a language it was built to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: So this question is about 2 (or more) threads talking to MySQL over the same connection?

Comment: If my answer fit you, please feel free to upvote it. Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look to these resources:

- [MySQL: Transactions across multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2495628/492638)
- [How we enabled threading in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/16/how-we-enabled-threading-in-mysql/)
- [MySQL Reference Manual – Server System Variables: `thread_concurrency`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL should automatically unlock the tables (and if you're using a transactional table type it'll do something with the transaction - either roll back or commit depending on options etc)  when the second process dies (since the connection will drop.) If your question is about having two processes for reliability working on a single work queue, that info may help?